# Installation Slack 3.3.1

Tags: software-installation

Hi guys Im installing slack but is sending an error:

```
surface@surface:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i slack-desktop-3.3.1-amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 203164 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack slack-desktop-3.3.1-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking slack-desktop (3.3.1) over (3.3.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of slack-desktop:
 slack-desktop depends on gconf2; however:
  Package gconf2 is not installed.
 slack-desktop depends on gconf-service; however:
  Package gconf-service is not installed.
 slack-desktop depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package slack-desktop (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2+elementary2~ubuntu0.4.1.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slack-desktop
```

I tryed to install the missin libraries but is not possible.

I found some giudes and each is based on older verson of slack, I have 2 questions:

1.- this error has fox?
2.- do you have an old version of slack to try install it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -i` is a really low level way of installing a `.deb` file and does not handle dependencies at all. I would suggest removing slack again using `sudo dpkg -r slack-desktop` and then re-installing using one of the following methods:

- Install [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/) from the AppCenter and install the .deb file via that.
- Use `sudo apt install ./slack-desktop-3.3.1-amd64.deb` or `sudo apt install /path/to/slack-desktop-3.3.1-amd64.deb`

Both of these methods should resolve dependencies for Slack and install them automatically. If these solutions don't help you, please post further information and terminal output regarding the issues you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in elementary OS but you seem to be missing some packages, I know for sure that [gconf2 exists in debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=gconf2&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all), try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf2 gconf-service libappindicator1
```

Please try to investigate why those packages gconf2, gconf-service and libappindicator1 are not included because installing it can cause the installation of unwanted packages or conflicts with your currently installed ones.

Regards.

Comment: all the packages was fixed using ``` sudo apt --fix-broken install``` but I think something is wrong, anyway thanks